# Changing the text of clicked link that triggers a jQuery slideToggle?

Tags: jquery

I have two elements one in top of the other:

```
<form class="order-form"></form>
<a href="#" class="hide-details">Hide Details</a>
```

I'm using the jQuery slideToggle:

```
  // Show/Hide Details
   $("a.hide-details").click(function () {
    $(".order-form").slideToggle(0);
   });
```

I would like the text "Hide Details" to change to "Show details" after the form is collapsed. And when the form is expanded I would like to change the text to "Hide Details" again.

Any suggestions to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change the text of your anchor:

```
// Show/Hide Details
$("a.hide-details").click(function () {
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.prev(".order-form").slideToggle(0, function() {
    $this.text($(this).is(':visible') ? "Show details": "Hide details");
  });
});
```

**EDIT** `prev` to get the previous form

Comment: Thanks but it is changing the text of the form not of the link

Comment: For some reason it is collapsing and expanding all the forms (there are many of the same forms).

Answer (score 2):

If you pass a function into `slideToggle` it will execute once it is finished. Once this occurs you can check to see if it is hidden or not and then display the appropriate text.

The code is untested :)

```
// Show/Hide Details
$("a.hide-details").click(function () {
    $(".order-form").slideToggle(0,function(){
        if ($(this).is(":hidden")) $(".hide-details").html("Show Details");
        else $(".hide-details").html("Hide Details");
    });
});
```

P.s. If you simply want to toggle the visiblity of an element with no animation [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) will work.

Answer (score 1):

```
 $("a.hide-details").click(function () {       
                var txt=$(this).text(); 
                (txt == 'Hide Details') ? txt='Show details':txt='Hide Details';
                $(".order-form").slideToggle(400,function(){        
                    $("a.hide-details").text(txt);
            });
        });
```